# To mark up in retail by $20$%, do I add $0.20$ times the original cost, or divide by $0.80$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

Why is it that when I take a cost of say $\$15.60$ and want to mark the item up at retail 20% that I'm being told two different ways with two different answers? 
The first way (my way) would be to multiply the original cost by $.20$ to get $20$%, then simply add that number to original cost. The second way is to take the original cost and divide it by $.80$ and the number you get ends up being the cost. But this second way is more than the first. The second way almost adds an extra $5$%.

Why are these different, and which is the proper way to mark up by a percentage?

Comment: Because the second way "adding 20 points" makes them more money and screws over the innumerate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second calculation you described is incorrect.

If I say, "Mark up by 20%," that generally means to increase the item's cost by 20% of its original value; i.e., if the item costs 100 dollars, then a 20% increase means to add 20 dollars to its original value, for a total cost of 120 dollars.

To see why the second calculation doesn't make sense, suppose I wanted to double to cost of the item:  this represents a **100 percent markup**.  If you tried to do that with your second method, you would end up dividing by zero!

So, what does the second calculation represent?  The result of such a calculation represents the price of an item that, if discounted by 20%, would give you the original price.  So if the original price was 100 dollars, 100/0.8 = 125 dollars.  This is the price of an item whose 20% discount would equal 100 dollars.  And now we see why the previous calculation resulted in division by zero:  if I asked you what price an item would need to be such that a 100% discount would make the new price 100 dollars, clearly that's a nonsensical statement, for a 100% discount means to make the item free.

Answer (score 1):

Simply because adding $0.2x$ to $x$, giving you $1.2x$, is **not** the same thing as $x/0.8$. This is because

$$1/0.8 = 1.25$$

You're not increasing by the same factor, the second option would be $1.25x$ instead of the very correct $1.2x$.